# Allow only one session per user in Remote Desktop Windows Vista Business

Tags: windows-vista, remote-desktop

I used to connect to this PC via remote desktop when it had WinXp, and all worked fine.

Since it has Windows Vista Business, when i login, another session is created for the same user, so i cant's see or have access to the applications already opened by that user.

What i want is the same behavior of remote desktop in WinXp Pro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To connect to the server's console, try using:

```
mstsc /v:<server> /admin
```

Or without SP1:

```
mstsc /v:<server> /console
```

Comment: What looks strange to me is the fact that this way the Remote Desktop didn't ask me for any user/password.

Comment: It has probably cached the last-used credential. It doesn't do this for all configurations, so you just lucked out.